# Stuck with the use of Express application with Node and jQuery / AJAX .

Tags: jquery, ajax, express

I have a question regarding the use of Express application with Node and jQuery / AJAX .

I have created a very simple movie search application. You can view the application here: https://aqueous-headland-41998.herokuapp.com/

I am using the www.omdbapi.com API to search for a movie title.
The application consists of 2 routes, the "/ " which serves the search page and the "/results" route to show the results based of the search criteria. 
The search button is a GET request to the omdb api.

Now I would like to make the search results below the search bar in the first screen with an AJAX call.
In the route: “/results” I am intercepting the AJAX call:

```
app.get('/results', function(req, res) {
    // info from the query string
    var apikey = '&apikey=ed6ba6e4';
    var query = req.query.search;
    var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + query + apikey;
    request(url, function(err, response, body) {
        // turn the body string into a JSON (javascript object)
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (req.xhr) {
                res.json(body);
            } else {
                res.render('results', {
                    data: results
                });
            }
            //res.send(results["Search"][0]['Title'])
        } else {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
});
```

My ajax.js file with the get is looking like this now but it’s not working.

```
$.get('/results', function(data) {
        data.Search.forEach(function(data) {
            debugger
            console.log(data.Title);
        });
});
```

Any suggestions how I would make the AJAX call working?

Many thanks!
Lino

Comment: What do you mean by "The AJAX call is not working"? What is the exact error?

Comment: Your `$.get` should be served to the client, but when I navigate to the heroku url you pasted, I see neither jQuery, nor your custom JavaScript on the page. Are you sure you're added the correct `<script>` tag sourcing your `ajax.js`?

Comment: sorry guys, the application on heroku is the one which is working. I have tried to refactor the working app with an AJAX call so that the first page will have the output of the results page/route. I have not deployed the not working app. I will try to do that this evening. The search page is "hanging" when I have chaned the "/:" route with the if (req.xhr) statement